# Eliminar objetos iguales en un array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

tengo el siguiente objeto:

```
 productos: [
    {"id":1,"cantidad":1,"nombre":"Bombilla individual E14","precio":60,"total":60},
    {"id":1,"cantidad":1,"nombre":"Bombilla individual E14","precio":60,"total":60},
    {"id":1,"cantidad":1,"nombre":"Bombilla individual E14","precio":60,"total":60},
    {"id":6,"cantidad":1,"nombre":"Pack de un A60 E27 filamento estándar","precio":19.95,"total":19.95},
    {"id":16,"cantidad":1,"nombre":"Foco empotrable Centura","precio":64.95,"total":64.95},
 ]
```

Lo que necesito es eliminar todos mis valores repetidos (No necesito que quede uno de los repetidos, necesito eliminar todos los repetidos.)

De manera que quede algo asi:

```
     sinDuplicados: [
        {"id":6,"cantidad":1,"nombre":"Pack de un A60 E27 filamento estándar","precio":19.95,"total":19.95},
        {"id":16,"cantidad":1,"nombre":"Foco empotrable Centura","precio":64.95,"total":64.95},
     ]
```

E intentado esto:

```
let set = new Set( this.productos.map( JSON.stringify ) )
let arrSinDuplicaciones = Array.from( set ).map( JSON.parse );
```

Pero siempre me queda un objeto de los repetidos.

Comment: es mas dificil de lo que parece, ya que javascript siempre toma dos objetos como diferentes asi tengan propiedades y valores exactamente iguales, si quieres una solucion que funcione para cualquier tipo de objeto simplemente no la vas a hayar, debido a que un objeto contiene o puede contener mucha recursividad, hacer ese tipo de comparaciones recursivas consume algo de recursos, lo que yo haria seria ir llenando un objeto vacio de referencia el cual contendra las propiedades y valores sin repetir, y en caso de que alguna se repita exactamente no anadir ese objeto a esa lista.

Comment: De hecho eso de repetir los objetos es a propósito, tengo un método en el cual almaceno objetos repetidos para luego crear otro objeto y sumar la cantidad de acuerdo a la cantidad (Valga la redundancia) de objetos que existen.

Comment: No importa si es o no aproposito, el tema es que deberas implementar la recursividad de manera especifica para tu `json` para poder comparar que el objeto es exactamente igual (tiene las mismas propiedades y valores), ya que una propiedad puede tener subpropieadedes, en tu caso no las hay, pero es una posibilidad que hay que tomar en cuenta.

Comment: Esta pregunta está duplicado quien me ayuda a buscarla

Answer (score 0):

El problema seguramente está en la forma en que conviertes tu JSON a objeto de Javascript, prueba con estas modificaciones.

```js
var productos = JSON.parse(`[{
    "id": 1,
    "cantidad": 1,
    "nombre": "Bombilla individual E14",
    "precio": 60,
    "total": 60
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "cantidad": 1,
    "nombre": "Bombilla individual E14",
    "precio": 60,
    "total": 60
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "cantidad": 1,
    "nombre": "Bombilla individual E14",
    "precio": 60,
    "total": 60
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "cantidad": 1,
    "nombre": "Pack de un A60 E27 filamento estándar",
    "precio": 19.95,
    "total": 19.95
  },
  {
    "id": 16,
    "cantidad": 1,
    "nombre": "Foco empotrable Centura",
    "precio": 64.95,
    "total": 64.95
  }
]`);

let set = new Set(this.productos.map(JSON.stringify))
let arrSinDuplicaciones = Array.from(set).map(JSON.parse);

console.log(arrSinDuplicaciones);
```

Partiendo de allí, te toca modificar donde tienes el set para que elimine todos los duplicados.

Comment: Esto resolveria el problema de que el `json no sea valido` pero no resolveria el problema de que los objetos que tengan las mismas propiedades y valores que otro se eliminen y solo quede uno de ellos.

Comment: @Riven eso mismo traté de decir.

Answer (score 0):

En realidad queres quedarte solo con los elementos que aparecen una sola vez

Deberias hacer algo como esto:

```
const productos = [
  {"id":1,"cantidad":1,"nombre":"Bombilla individual E14","precio":60,"total":60},
  {"id":1,"cantidad":1,"nombre":"Bombilla individual E14","precio":60,"total":60},
  {"id":1,"cantidad":1,"nombre":"Bombilla individual E14","precio":60,"total":60},
  {"id":6,"cantidad":1,"nombre":"Pack de un A60 E27 filamento estándar","precio":19.95,"total":19.95},
  {"id":16,"cantidad":1,"nombre":"Foco empotrable Centura","precio":64.95,"total":64.95}
];

// no prestar atencion a los nombres de las variables jaja
const contadorDeIds = {};

productos.forEach(p => {
  // no existe el id en el elemento, ponemos el contador en 1
  if(!contadorDeIds[p.id]) {
    contadorDeIds[p.id] = 1
  } else {
    // ya existe, le sumamos 1
    contadorDeIds[p.id] += 1;
  }
});

const productosQueAparecenUnaSolaVez = productos.filter(p => {
  // te quedas solo con los elementos cuyo contador sea 1
  return contadorDeIds[p.id] === 1
});
```